# Calling all title (& probably alt) attributes by jQuery - and CSS-ing them on hover?

Tags: jquery, css

Ok there is a huge amount of title (and alt) attributes all around any page I guess. To be honest, I have been dressing those up so far with SweetTitles (js library), but since my page supports jQuery, I would like to make that more faster and more firm with jQuery.

Any suggestions what to write into jQuery and .css to call a title (and alt) attributes on hover - without adding ids to those?

**NOTE: Sry I meant on those title and alt attributes in links and images... like**

```
<img src="something.jpg **alt**="This is image"> or <a href="something.php" **title**="Go to this page">
```

**title**=

Comment: What browsers are you supporting? It can be done with simple css to a point.

Comment: umm.. Add a class=foo attribute to all the tags and then use $(".foo").each function to iterate and get the id using $this.attr lemme know if you need exmple; OR I might got your question wrong in that case let me know I will remove this comment, cheers

Comment: @ Andres.. I support any other browser then IE6.. yes I guess its a simple stuff and thx to guys but I guess I have been missunderstood :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** In your case, you may need as below,

```
img[alt] { /* set style for all img tag with alt attr */ }
a[title] { /* set style for all link tag with title attr */ }
```

Same logic applies jQuery:

```
$('img[alt]') //will return all img tags with alt attribute
$('a[title]') //will return all link tags with title attribute
```

---

You need to read about `attribute selectors` in jQuery and css. See below links,

[jQuery Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

[CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

I created a simple example to show you how to use attribute selector in css and jQuery. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/99mFF/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div title="test" ></div>
<div title="test2"></div>

<div title="test" ></div>
<div title="test2"></div>

<div title="test" ></div>
<div title="test2"></div>

<div title="test" ></div>
<div title="test2"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div { width: 20px; height: 10px; margin: 10px; display: inline-block; }

div[title=test] { border: 1px solid red; }

div[title=test2] { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

**JS:**

```
$('div[title=test]').css ('background-color', 'red');

$('div[title=test2]').css ('background-color', 'blue');
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @Joseph See my edits and let me know if that clarifies your question.

Comment: Yes thats it!!!!!!!!!:)))) Can you just point me how to apply css on it since I'm just learning jquery, thx

Comment: This answer is proper; but matching with element attributes (as you're doing here) is significantly slower than using IDs and classes, if you can use those instead...

Comment: I can use ids, but portal runs 1k+ pages, it would take me 2 weeks to set that up but ill try.... After all I want to make it faster. Thx guys..

Answer (score 0):

You could try somthing like the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("body *").each(function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr("title") != undefined && $(this).attr("title") != "") {
            // do work
        }
        if ($(this).attr("alt") != undefined && $(this).attr("alt") != "") {
            // do work
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Sry I edited main question, you think this will do? If yes, can you point me how to apply that to specific css, ie. .image_title { font-size:10px; }?

Comment: Not really I have no codes since I dont have any idea how to write those. Its a sort of tooltip similar to this.. http://www.webappers.com/2007/08/23/sweet-titles-transparent-and-fading-tooltips/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a paragraph with title.

In css you could have:

```
p[title='something']:hover{
//my css rules here
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$("p[title='something']").hover(function(){
// my code comes here
})
```